# psql autocomplete on windows

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is it possible to make autocomplete working in `psql` on Windows?
As I know from Linux users, they can make use pressing `TAB` to autocomplete, which is quite handy, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

`psql`'s autocompletion comes by virtue of the readline or libedit library, whichever was configured when PostgreSQL was built from source. The Windows binaries were built without that support, most likely because there are no Windows ports of these libraries. If you port either of these libraries to Windows, you can build PostgreSQL from source and enjoy command line completion.

Comment: How would I do this? By now I downloaded the files provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26441939/15307393

Comment: If you ask that, you are probably not knowledgeable enough to do this. If it were simple, PostgreSQL would come with command line completion by default.

Comment: What´s about Clink (https://chrisant996.github.io/clink/) ?

Comment: Perhaps PostgreSQL could be modified to use that. But that would require research and modifications of the PostgreSQL source.

Answer (score 1):

Though `psql.exe` does not have autocomple support, you can install `psql` on [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).